# How to print star pattern in java

Tags: java

I tried to find any sequence or formula for below star pattern but i did not found, so simply tried below

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {


        System.out.println("....*....");
        System.out.println("...***...");
        System.out.println("*********");
        System.out.println(".*******.");
        System.out.println("*********");
        System.out.println("...***...");
        System.out.println("....*....");

    }
}
```

Here "." means " " space character.
Can we print this star using loop ?

[image]

Comment: This is probably homework.  Have you tried anything yourself yet?  Note that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing/homework service.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but if you really want a loop, here is a solution!

```
public class Star {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] dots = new int[] {4, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 4};
        int width= 9;

        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                if (j < dots[i] || j > width - dots[i] - 1) {
                    System.out.print(".");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much @MWB, I never saw this approach, I havent posted my actual effort as that was getting very tricky and complex logic for me to explain, hence to not confuse I have just added println statements.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Hope It Helps! This is Easy to understand for Low Class Students Rather than Creating Arrays

```
class starPattern {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        for(int i=1;i<=7;i++) {
            for(int j=1;j<=9;j++) {
                if(i==3 || i==5 || j==5 || (i==4 && j>1 && j<9) || ((i==2 || i==6) && (j>3 && j<7))) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }else{
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

My Computer Teacher Check it and it was Correct Method!

A Brief Description About this Pattern

```
1↓  1→  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
2                   *               
3               *   *   *           
4   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
5       *   *   *   *   *   *   *   
6   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
7               *   *   *           
8                   *
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Java 11. You should be able to draw any enantiomorphic pattern of asterisks. Read the comments for detailed explanation.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class Star {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] stars = new int[] { 1, 3, 9, 7, 9, 3, 1 }; // asterisks per line
        int max = Arrays.stream(stars).max().getAsInt(); // max asterisks in any line
        for (int i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) { // prints the asterisks for a given row, and pads it left and right with spaces
            System.out.print(" ".repeat((max - stars[i]) / 2) + "*".repeat(stars[i]) + " ".repeat((max - stars[i] + 1) / 2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it can be done using loops and should not be done via sout statements. 
Also seems like you are a beginner in programming, so I will suggest you to try out logic for these kind of questions yourself. It will help in your growth.

Just try out line by line.
These questions generally need 2 loops, one to move in vertical direction and other to move  in horizontal direction.
You can think it of as a i*j matrix( eg 3X3, 4X4).

So try it out yourself start with some basic one's.
If you still need solution just ping me but please try it on your own first.

Comment: Since i cannot add a comment to your question, so I had to post it in answer.